# Is this function of Semi-definite matrices, convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is the following function is convex. Consider the following function

$$ f(X)=\langle X,D\rangle-c \cdot \sqrt{\langle X,E\rangle}$$ where $X,D,E$ are all semi-definite matrices.
Is this function convex?

Comment: What is $c$? ${}{}$

Comment: c is a positive constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked @copper.hat above about the minimum. Without the semidefinite constraint, the function is likely unbounded below except for certain combinations of $D$ and $E$ (e.g, $D=\alpha E$ for some $\alpha>0$; see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180482/gradient-and-hessian-of-a-function-with-matrix-variables) to your other question).

With the semidefinite constraint, it is unlikely there is an analytic solution. You'll need a semidefinite programming framework to determine the constrained minimum. If you use my [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) framework, for instance, this is your model:

```
n = size(D,1);
cvx_begin
    variable X(n,n) semidefinite
    minimize( trace(X'*D)-c*sqrt(trace(X'*E)) ) 
cvx_end
```

Internally, CVX will convert this to a semidefinite program and pass it to a compatible solver.

EDIT: I take that back, I do believe you can determine the solution analytically, but it's not easy, and there still is not a closed-forum solution. This will certainly be quicker for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Michael Grant. How such a problem can be converted to an ordinary semidefinite program? Actually, my problem is to find a very scalable way to solve this problem. Could you give me some hint about the way CVX convert this problem to a semidefinite program? Do you have any suggestions, How to make this problem more scalable?

Comment: Could you give tell me how to determine the solution analytically, and is it faster?

Comment: I'm afraid I am out of time today. But in short I would construct the dual problem. My belief is that the dual can be solved with a single generalized eigenvalue decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

The function $X \mapsto \langle X,D \rangle$ is linear, hence convex. Same
for $X \mapsto \langle X,E \rangle$.

The function $t \mapsto -c \sqrt{t}$ is convex for $t \ge 0$, hence $f$ is convex.

Comment: thank you. Could you tell anything about it's minimum?

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me...