# "Quadratic" form between a 4th order tensor and a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I would like to work out the following formulation. Consider a function $f($**S**$)$, where **S** is a matrix. If I want to compute the second order derivative of the function I have:

$$ G_{i jkl}=\frac{\partial f(S)}{\partial S_{i j} \partial  S_{k l}}$$

and hence I can write the differential df(S) as:

$$df(S)= \sum_{ij} \sum_{kl} G_{ijkl} \partial S_{ij} \partial S_{kl}= \sum_{ij} \partial S_{i j}  \langle G_{ij}, \partial S \rangle_{F}$$
How can I continue to write the above equation in a "quadratic" form similar to $xAx$ for vector-matrix-vector but now with matrix-tensor-matrix?

Thank you

Comment: If $S$ is a matrix, how does it have four indices?

Comment: @Chrystomath sorry, I just corrected it now.

Comment: It's still not clear. What is $\partial S_{ij}$?

Comment: Because the variable is the matrix **S**, I derive with respect each entry $S_{ij}$

Comment: In general, a Taylor expansion gives $f(S+H)=f(S)+df(S)H+\frac{1}{2}Q.H.H+\cdots$. $df$ would be a $(2,0)$-tensor and $Q$ a $(4,0)$-tensor.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know it. I am saying how can I formally write the term that involves the Hessian that is a 4th order tensor. There is a notation for it? I would like to continue my equation in formulae.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110414/discussion-between-chrystomath-and-alberto).