# Gradient of a function with matrix variables $V(Q) = \|Q-Q_N\|^2_F\big[-\ln(-\frac{\langle D-dI,Q \rangle}{2})\big]$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I followed the following discussion:  [Gradient and Hessian of a function with Matrix Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180482/gradient-and-hessian-of-a-function-with-matrix-variables)

$V(Q) = \|Q-Q_N\|^2_F\big[-\ln(-\frac{\langle D-dI,Q \rangle}{2})\big]$

I want to calculate $\nabla_Q V(Q)$, where $Q_N$, $D$ are constant square matrix. $Q$ is a square matrix variable.

So I did the following

1. Find $$\nabla_Q \|Q-Q_N\|_F^2=\nabla_Q\text{tr}[(Q-Q_N)^T(Q-Q_N)]=\nabla_Q\langle Q,Q \rangle-2\nabla_Q\langle Q,Q_N \rangle+\nabla_Q\langle Q_N,Q_N \rangle=2(Q-Q_N)$$
2. Find $$\nabla_Q -\ln\bigg(-\frac{\langle D-dI,Q \rangle}{2}\bigg)=-\frac{D-dI}{\langle D-dI,Q\rangle}$$

So $$\nabla_Q V(Q)=2(Q-Q_N)\bigg[-\ln\bigg(-\frac{\langle D-dI,Q \rangle}{2}\bigg)\bigg]+ \|Q-Q_N\|_F^2\bigg[ -\frac{D-dI}{\langle D-dI,Q\rangle}\bigg]$$

Am I correct?  Please let me know your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right to me. The result actually holds in any real Hilbert space; if we set

$$ V_1(v):= \|v\|^2, \quad V_2(v) := v-v_0,\quad  V_2(v):=-\ln\langle c,v\rangle$$
then
\begin{align}
dV_1(v)h&=2\langle v,h\rangle
\\
dV_2(v)h &= h 
\\
dV_3(v)h &= \frac{-1}{ \langle c,v\rangle}\langle c,h\rangle
\end{align}
And by chain and product rule, the derivative of $V(v) := (V_1\circ V_2)(v)V_3(v)=-\|v-v_0\|^2\ln \langle c,v\rangle $ is
$$ dV(v)h = -2\langle v-v_0,h\rangle\ln \langle c,v\rangle  - \|v-v_0\|^2\frac{\langle c,h\rangle}{\langle c,v\rangle} $$
So the gradient vector (i.e. the vector $u=\nabla V(v)$ such that $\langle u,h\rangle = dV(v) h)$  is
$$\nabla V(v) = -2\ln\langle c,v\rangle (v-v_0) -  \|v-v_0\|^2\frac{ c}{\langle c,v\rangle} $$